# PrimeNG Accordion expand all/collapse all

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am looking for a way to Open and Close the entire accordion with one button. Right now I'm doing it like this. Currently only the expansion works but the collapse does not for some reason. I checked and the tab.selected is getting set to False on collapse, but it won't close

`openCloseAllProjectStatusTabs(requestToOpen: boolean) {`
`if (this.projectStatusTabs !== undefined && this.projectStatusTabs != null){`
`this.projectStatusTabs.forEach(tab => tab.selected = requestToOpen);`
`this.expanded = requestToOpen;`
`}`
`}`

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test this code, but I think all you need is to give the `p-accordion` the `multiple` flag. Then all you need to do is a single `isExpanded` value that will control all of the tabs using the `selected` input.

##### app.component.html

```html
<p-accordion [multiple]="true">
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 1" [selected]="isExpanded">
    <p>
      Content 1
    </p>
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 2" [selected]="isExpanded">
    <p>
     content 2
    </p>
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 3" [selected]="isExpanded">
    <p>
      content 3
    </p>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>

<button (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded">Toggle</button>
```

##### app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 

  private _isExpanded = false;
  
  public get isExpanded() {
    return this._isExpanded;
  }

  public set isExpanded(value: boolean) {
     this._isExpanded = value;
  }
}
```